# Can Android Device be flashed without using Host PC? Can we flash full SW image using sdcard/external USB storage

Tags: rom-flashing, flashtool

For all Android Products there are 2 ways to flash the SW image:

1. EDL Mode(Emergency Download Mode) - Normally used when bootloader can't be booted up or for first flash
2. fastboot mode

Both of above method requires flashing via USB connected to Host PC.

Query:
Do we have any alternative way to re-flash full SW image to Android Device which does not bootup without using HOST PC?

Comment: it's possible to run fastboot from another android device as host. flashing ROM from SD Card on device itself is possible in recovery mode

Comment: @alecx thanks. But recovery mode will not help if device is not bootable. It also can’t enter recovery mode. Do you have any suggestion/detailed steps how can we run fastboot from another device as host and flash.

Comment: there is a [Magisk module](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/adb-ndk/blob/master/update.json) for this